# I want to have a private iOS app, can I pay only the $99 fee and have users as beta testers forever?

Tags: ios, ipad, private, beta

I want to have a private iOS app, can I pay only the $99 fee and have my users as beta testers forever?

Also, do apps running in this way have the same performance as ones that have officially passed out of beta?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you are limited to 100 testers a year per the iTunes developer agreement. Performance is the same.

Comment: I thought you need to pay $99 **per year**. Otherwise your mobile provisions expire.

Comment: I thought the beta testing profile contained in the beta app would expire and would forbid the tester to launch the app until the profile is updated...

Comment: You are right… I haven't had my coffee yet :P

Answer (score 2):

There are three types of distribution:

- App Store
- Ad hoc
- Enterprise

I don't believe that any of these will allow use "forever." Each has an annual fee. *Ad hoc* has a certificate that expires and has a limit of 100 devices.

Distribution provides just a signature that is checked by iOS on installation. It has zero effect on performance.